# Flutter package for Firebase In-App Messaging not building for ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-in-app-messaging

Flutter package for Firebase In-App Messaging not building for ios
As title:

firebase_in_app_messaging: "0.1.1+3"

After adding the above in the pubspec.yaml file, the project cannot build for ios.
Conflicts with:
1. SwiftContactsServicePlugin
2. SafariServices
3. url_launcher
4. FirebaseMessaging
5. GoogleMobileAds

Any ideas?